# vs code mac dotnet maui build error codesign issue (resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed)

Tags: maui

Any idea why I'm getting this error in VSCode on Mac: resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed

I want to target Mac Catalyst and iOS.

The full error is displayed below:

/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.MacCatalyst.Sdk/17.2.8043/tools/msbuild/iOS/Xamarin.Shared.targets(2257,3): error : /usr/bin/codesign exited with code 1: [/Application/Application.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-maccatalyst]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.MacCatalyst.Sdk/17.2.8043/tools/msbuild/iOS/Xamarin.Shared.targets(2257,3): error : /Application/Application/bin/Debug/net8.0-maccatalyst/maccatalyst-x64/Application.app: resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed [/Application/Application/Application.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-maccatalyst]

I've tried this, but it doesn't fix the issue.

Firstly tried
https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/21213

then tried
xattr -c .

finally tried:

dotnet clean
rm -rf ./bin
rm -rf ./obj
xattr -cr .

Any ideas?  This is a new project and I have installed the maui workload and I have an apple dev account.

Comment: why has this question been downgraded without any comment as to why this is?